# If $A, B \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ are nonsymmetric matrices, what can we do to bound $\lambda_{\max}(AB)$?

Tags: inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I think my title illustrates my question pretty clear. I know that there is an obvious bound when A and B are normal matrices ($\lambda_\max(AB)=\rho(AB) \leq \rho(A) \rho(B)=\lambda_\max(A)\lambda_\max(B)$), but are there any bounds for nonsymmetric real matrices? Or, under what circumstances can on derive a bound? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ... _I know that there is an obvious bound when $A$ and $B$ are normal matrices_ ... isn't a good substitute for explicitly writting down **the obvious bound**. The body of your post should be more substantive for the benefit of yourself and others.

Comment: @Invisible Clearified that, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary matrices we always have a bound derived from the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm), namely

$$\rho(AB) \le \| AB \| \le \| A \| \| B \|.$$

If $A$ and $B$ aren't normal then this bound doesn't reduce to any kind of bound involving their eigenvalues; e.g. if $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right], B = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$ then $A$ and $B$ are both nilpotent so have only zero eigenvalues, but

$$AB = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$$

satisfies $\rho(AB) = 1$. We do have $\| A \| = \| B \| = 1$ so the operator norm bound is tight in this case.

Comment: Yes, and I found that deriving bounds on the singular values of $AB$ seems more plausible.